# How can this summation be written in terms of hypergeometric function?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I came across an expression as

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}(n-k)^{2n-1}.  
\end{equation}

It seems similar to the definition of the hypergeometric function, is it possible to rewrite it into the hypergeometric function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it corresponds more to [the Generalized_hypergeometric_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Notation)

Comment: See [OEIS A$25585$](http://oeis.org/A025585).

Comment: @user1952009, could you please elaborate a little bit since I am not familiar with this kind of function. Thanks a lot!